# Extract Matching List of Keywords

Tags: excel, database, extract, excel-2019

I have a huge amount of data that has no consistent sentence formatting, and I have a list of keywords I refer to. Whenever a keyword exists in the data, I want to extract them out onto another column. [examples of how I want keywords to be extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8im7.png)
I don't mind if it gives "red apple" and "apple"

Currently I'm just using filters to find cells that has the same words, so I can key in extracted keywords as a batch/group

Comment: For first one, you have both `apple` and `red apple`. It should return both as result.

Comment: @BingShuen what is your excel version? If it is not the current one, then it needs to be indicated as a tag in your question. [Here](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates.htm) you can find the functions available based on version

Comment: @DavidLeal Thank you for your comment. the current version im using is Professional Plus 2019 and for some reason I can't update. I will look at the link you commented with. Again, appreciate your help

Comment: As @Harun24hr pointed out it is possible to find both `apple` and `red apple` for row one, but I am not aware on how to just find `red apple` considering also your excel version limitations.

Comment: I dont mind if it outputs apple in 1 column, and red apple the next. And ya my excel version is 2019. clicked update but it says im using the latest

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula-

```
=BYROW(A2:A4,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(F2:F5,COUNTIFS(x,"*"&F2:F5&"*")>0))))
```

[image]

Comment: The BYROW isnt recognized. also FILTER doesnt work for me. the only option of functions excel had was FILTERXML

Comment: Then you are using older version.